# Javascript - Array parameter becomes concatenated

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am new to Javascript and am attempting to pass in an array of strings as a parameter to a synchronous function. Inside the function the array gets combined into one string and I am not sure why. The input is structured so that I cannot change it.

```
module.exports = {
    myFunc: function (input) {
        console.log(input); //"string1string2,string3"

        var type = input[0];
        var val = input[1][0];
        console.log('type: ' + type +  ', val: ' + val) 
    }
}


myFunc(["string1", ["string2", "string3"]]); //'type: s, val: t'
```

The param `input` gets concatenated with all three string, becomes `string1string2,string3` and prints out `'type: s, val: t'`.

Comment: What do you mean by "intact"? Don't concatenate on `input` -- leave it be! Just flatten and join the array, then return that. `input` is still the original array.

Comment: Did you leave out some code? Assuming the typo is just from copying it over (after 'string2'), your function wouldn't return anything. The only thing it'd do is `console.log('type: string1, val: string2')`.

Comment: You are missing a double quotation mark in string2

Comment: Yeah it was a copy and paste error

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to accomplish here can you explain it a bit better. What do you want the function to do exactly? The reason I ask this is your using an array for specific object which is not really needed. You might be better off using object instead of array.

Comment: @DerekLawrence I edited the question a bit. I cannot change the structure of the input, this is how it comes in when I pass it to myFunc(). For some reason it is getting concatenated automatically.

Comment: i suggest console logging the input at the start of the function so that you can see what you get in the function and maybe start understanding what is going on

Comment: @Isac I edited the answer with the console output entering the function

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript seems to be working fine as you can see here:

```js
var myFunc = function (input) {
    var type = input[0];
    var val = input[1][0];
    console.log('type: ' + type +  ', val: ' + val) 
}

myFunc(["string1", ["string2", "string3"]]); //'type: s, val: t'
```

I had to remove the modules so i could run it in the snippet

Comment: This is not how my code is working in my nodejs program. It is printing out `'type: s, val: t' ` which is why i asked the question

Comment: @McLovin Then there is something not right between the code sample you provided and what it'll do. Isac showed it does exactly what I mentioned in a previous comment.

Comment: I think you'll have to post more code so that we can help you, the function that you posted seems fine.

Comment: This is literally all of the code. Could it be a Node.js thing that's making it do this possibly?

Comment: Check my answer. I think I have an idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The code example you gave doesn't give the output you claim it does.

However, I suspect you might have something like this:

```js
const myFunc = function (input) {
  var type = input[0];
  var val = input[1][0];
  console.log('type: ' + type +  ', val: ' + val) 
}


myFunc("string1", ["string2", "string3"]); //'type: s, val: t'
```

Notice, I removed the outer array from your example. If you call just `myFunc("string1")`, you get the output you are claiming to get.

I suspect you are missing one level of array that your function is expecting.

What's happening instead is it is being accessed as a string instead of an array.

```js
const str = 'abcdef';
console.log(str[0]);
console.log(str[1]);
console.log(str[1][0]);
console.log(str[1][1]);
console.log(str[1][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]);
```

Notice how you can access a single character of a string with an array-like syntax. However, unlike other languages, in JavaScript, a single character of a string is still a string, so you can actually call `[0]` on that an infinite number of times and still get that character back.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. So if this is not possible in Javascript then there is definitely something screwey going on. I added the console.log of the input upon entering the function. I am executing this exactly how it is written in my question with a 2d array.

Comment: Either you aren't calling it quite how you think, or perhaps you have some kind of funky transpilation issue going on. Are you writing this in pure JavaScript? Are you using anything like Babel, TypeScript, Coffee, etc?

Comment: If it isn't a funky transpilation going on, I almost guarantee that the value you're passing to 'myFunc()' is already messed up and concatenated.

Comment: Yes it is pure javascript. I'll have to do some more digging to see what's going on with transpilation issues

Comment: Just to note: I doubt it's a transpilation issue. If it is, it'd be a really weird one. My number one suspicion is that the value you're passing to myFunc() isn't what you think it is. I'd make sure to exhaustively explore that before looking at transpilation issues.